# How to store the body of an Email Template in a variable in a Salesforce flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, email-template, email-alert, sales-cloud

I have created a flow which sends out an email alert. After the email is sent, it creates a new Task record where in the Description field, I need to show the body of the email that was sent to the user.
Currently, I am using a text variable in the flow and copied the email body into it and assigned it to the new Task record. This is working well.
However, is there a way to fetch and store the email content directly from the template? I tried fetching the Email template record and assigning the body to the Description field of the Task, but after the Task record was created, the Description was blank.
Is it because the email content is HTML?

Fetching the Email Template:

[image: Get Email Template]

Created a formula to fetch the email template body depending on the criteria:
[image: Formula]

Assigned email body to Task Description:

[image: Task Assignment]